# Entity Framework - Code First - Many to Many Relationship Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I have a problem with Entity Framework which is driving me somewhat crazy.

I have two models as follows:

```
public class Day
{
  [Key]
  public int ID {get; set;}
  [Required]
  public int Name {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Event> Events {get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
  [Key]
  public int ID {get; set;}
  [Required]
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Day> Days {get; set;}
}
```

What I have specified is that 'Event' has a list of 'Day' and vice-versa.

Now 'Event' is a table which has rows constantly being added whilst 'Day' is a table which only contains 5 static rows (monday - friday)

The EF context also has model-building implemented as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasMany<Day>(s => s.Day)
            .WithMany(c => c.Events)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("EventId");
                cs.MapRightKey("DayId");
                cs.ToTable("EventDays");
            });
```

Now the problem occurs as follows:

When I add an 'Event' object into the context, which has a list of 'Days' included, apart from the entry being added to the 'EventDays' table, rows are being added into the 'Days' table with the selected days.

Image below shows the data outputted:

[Table Data - Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3qnA.png)

Why is this happening?

In my opinion, rows should only be added in the link-table which in this case is the 'EventDays' table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can find nobody else with this particular problem :/

Thanks

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Update:

When I retrieved the days from the database and added them to the event model manually, everything worked just fine.

Why is this? When I used entity framework before, you could just add the model with the nested objects and it would automatically attach them instead of adding more entries.

Comment: How are you inserting the data?  I suspect the problem is creating new days when adding records...

Comment: As an Aside, For something like this I'd use an Enum or just an int for days of the week and basically ditch the days table altogether.  Getting events on a particular day of the week could be easily done with code, and I can't see anyone adding a new weekday anytime soon.

Comment: Can you add the code that insert Event here, as @GPW said I think the problem is in adding the Event, You should select a day from already existing days in database rather than adding a new day.

Comment: The example I gave above is just for explanation purposes. In reality the object is much more complex. Basically I have a base object 'ModelA' which has a child 'ModelB'. This 'ModelB' then has a list of 'ModelC'. The code i am using to insert into the database is context.ModelA.Add(model); which is the standard provided by entity framework. For some reason when I add the model to the database, it links to 'ModelB' just fine as this is a one-to-one relationship, but instead of adding a row into the link-table between 'ModelB' and 'ModelC' it also adds a duplicate row into the 'ModelC' table.

Comment: I'm not an EF expert, but I think that it is something related to object tracking by EF. When you add the Day from already existing list in the database it can till that this value is already exists and add a link to it, but when you add a new Day to Event it will assume it is a new entry (It can't track it in the database and it will not perform string comparison to get Day ID) and add a new entry. You can add DayID only to Event (maybe from enum) with ID that is match that exists in Days table, that will work too as EF will know which value you mean.

Comment: And if you are asking why adding Day ID is enough to EF to know which entry you mean but Day Name is not enough, that because the ID is a primary key.

Comment: Right, if the day is not in tracking it will be added. So either fetch the days into the context or do `context.Entry(dayItem).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` before saving. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)